# Why does the ldd command on libzmq not show libsodium dependency?

Tags: cross-platform, cross-compiling, zeromq, pyzmq, libsodium

I have cross compiled `libsodium` and `libzmq`. I compiled `libzmq` with  the commands below :

```
./configure CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc                                \
        --host=arm-linux-gnueabi                                     \
        --target=arm-linux-gnueabi                                    \
        --build=x86_64-linux-gnu                                       \
        --enable-shared                                                 \
        --with-libsodium=/home/sagar/OtisSagar/libzmq/sodium_install/lib \
        --prefix=/home/sagar/libzmq/_install

make 

make install
```

The compilation is successful without any errors and I do see the libraries generated in the prefix directory but when I run the **`ldd`** on `libzmq`, it does not show the dependency of `libsodium` :

```
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x8badf00d)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x8badf00d)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x8badf00d)
    ld-linux.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0x8badf00d)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x8badf00d)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x8badf00d)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x8badf00d)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *What am I doing wrong here?*

Documentation <sub>*( Last Revised: 2017-06-11 )*</sub>  starts on this saying :

> <sub>The ZeroMQ library uses a slightly modified `CURVE` protocoll in order to secure your messages against manipulation and eaves-dropping.
>
>   
>
>   See https://curvecp.org/ and http://hintjens.com/blog:48 for detailed background.
>
>
>   If you enable `libsodium` the embedded files will not be used and instead the resulting library of ZeroMQ will be linked against the shared libsodium library.</sub>

Documentation also states a few defaults, that mean the `libsodium` **is not**, **unless explicitly requested** built against, in favour of `tweetnacl`<sup>**1**</sup>, further mentioning different settings for different build-systems :

> <sub>howto enable building with libsodium
>
>
>   **autoconf**
>   
>
>   - add the **`—with-libsodium`** switch to the configure script
>
>   
>
>   **cmake**
>
>   - add the **`-DWITH_LIBSODIUM=ON`** switch to the cmake call.</sub>

Last but not least :

> <sub>**Footnotes**
>
>   1. (*) this might currently not be true for all build systems, but this behaviour is the intention. Please submit PRs and pull requests for the non-behaving ones.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found out that the libsodium is not necessary for my application so, i have built without libsodium